# Discount for repeated for rows

Tags: python, mysql, django

User creates one plan to purchase some items on **N** (five) diff dates.

```
+--------------+---------+------------+
| plan_date_id | plan_id | ad_date    |
+--------------+---------+------------+
|            1 |       1 | 2015-09-13 |
|            2 |       1 | 2015-09-15 |
|            3 |       1 | 2015-09-17 |
|            4 |       1 | 2015-09-21 |
|            5 |       1 | 2015-09-24 |
+--------------+---------+------------+
```

**Week Span:** For each product week span will be calculated based on the date on which the product was sold for the first time + 6 to date part.

> i.e., for **product_ID 10**, first purchase was made on 2015-09-13, so
>   the week span will be from 2015-09-13 to 2015-09-19(2015-09-13 + 6).

**Discount logic for a product:**  *(Total No. of Repetition in a Week Span - 1) * 10%*.

**But maximum discount can be 30%.**

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| plan_product_id | plan_date_id | product_id |
+-----------------+--------------+------------+
|               1 |            1 |         10 |
|               2 |            2 |       5715 |
|               3 |            2 |         10 |
|               4 |            3 |         10 |
|               5 |            3 |     128900 |
|               6 |            4 |         10 |
|               7 |            5 |         10 |
+-----------------+--------------+------------+
```

So in my example I want discount as follow.

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
| plan_product_id | plan_date_id | product_id |   discount |
+-----------------+--------------+------------+------------+
|               1 |            1 |         10 |         0% |
|               2 |            2 |       5715 |         0% |
|               3 |            2 |         10 |        10% |
|               4 |            3 |         10 |        20% |
|               5 |            3 |     128900 |         0% |
|               6 |            4 |         10 |         0% |
|               7 |            5 |         10 |         0% |
+-----------------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

Please Note there will be **0% discount** in plan_product_id **6 and 7**

Currently, I am doing discount calculation in python.
First get all required records. Then create a dict with product_id as key,
in value there is another dict holding base date and repeated times in a week. Then loop to all record.

What will be the best way to do it?

Is it possible to do it only from MySQL or Django Orm?

Will looping in MySQL be more performance efficient?

Comment: can you place example data on http://www.sqlfiddle.com?